# Multitenant route api with react component

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

i am building a multitenant saas system, with laravel for backend and for my frontend i chose to use react js. But it is my first time i do this type of system (Tenant). So i have a question, how should i use tenant router? For example i need to do user management table with react component and i have `users` route on the `tenant.php` not on `web.php` but there is also a `api.php` On normal app we use router from api.php to interact data from controller to vue or react component. How should i use tenant route on this type of app?

I know i can use route directly from `tenant.php` but i mean is better to use from `api.php` ? I am loking for best practise

`web.php`

```
Route::redirect('/', 'login');

Auth::routes();

/**
 * Route group middleware
 * 
 */
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    // DASHBOARD
    Route::get('/dashboard', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

    // USERS MANAGEMENTS
    Route::resource('roles', RoleController::class);
    Route::resource('users', UserController::class);
    Route::resource('products', ProductController::class);
});
```

`tenant.php`

```
Route::middleware([
    'web',
    InitializeTenancyByDomain::class,
    PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class,
])->group(function () {
    // Route::get('/', function () {
    //     return view('auth.login');
    // });
    Route::redirect('/', 'login');

    Auth::routes();

    
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
        // DASHBOARD
        Route::get('/dashboard', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

        // USERS MANAGEMENTS
        Route::resource('roles', RoleController::class);
        Route::resource('users', UserController::class);
```

`api.php`

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a new folder in routes and name it tenant. And inside the tenant, I create a new route file for api called api.php and add it to my tenant.php route file.

Below my tenant.php I add this line
**require **DIR**.'/tenant/api.php';**

My **tenant\api.php** file

```
Route::middleware(['api', 'throttle:api',InitializeTenancyByDomain::class,
    PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class,])
    ->prefix('api/v1')
    ->name('tenant.')
    ->group(function () {
        // Api Routes
    });
```

From your react side just call api route with your subdomain name.
For central Domain **sass.test**
For tenant domain **test.sass.test\api\v1\users** it will point your tenant route for your test tenant

Comment: Sounds like a good logic, but Isn't this the same as using tenant.php? because in this way we are calling api.php in tenant.php . Is there any benefit to using this type of method?

Comment: I just test this method, but is not working very good for me, i have added the api.php inside the tenant folder inside routes folder, and the tenant.php i have let on the routes folder. I think this was what you suggest? And then inside api.php `->group(function () {// Api RoutesRoute::redirect('/', 'login');Auth::routes();` i have added this two routes. but iam not able to access with postman the login route `http://foo.localhost:8000/api/v1/login` i get this type of error `

Comment: "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "file": "C:\\Users\\ag\\Desktop\\Working\\Tetrix-CRM-Dev\\TetrixCRM\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php",
    "line": 1144,` aslo if i do `php artisan route:cache

   LogicException 

  Unable to prepare route [login] for serialization. Another route has already been assigned name [login].`  i also have these routes on my web.php couse i want to make login as tenant and also like central domain

Comment: It depends on you. You can create api routes within a tenant.php but folder better understanding I think creating a new file is better.

Comment: You need to add name for api routes just like that
Route::middleware(['api', 'throttle:api',InitializeTenancyByDomain::class,
    PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class,])
    ->prefix('api/v1')
    ->name('tenant.')
    ->group(function () {
        // Api Routes
    });

it will prevent your same name routes that's already created in web.php or tenant.php

Comment: I have tryed already this solution, but first problem comes when i run `php artisan route:cache` and second problem. There is still same response on the postman

Comment: Did you use Auth::routes(); for both web.php and tenant.php ? If yes please see this link for sanctum integration with multitenant
https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/integrations/sanctum
Or You can see check this boilerplate that use jetstream and sanctum 
https://github.com/MujeebAnwar/laravel_mutli_tenant

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your application and what do you have, from my point of view if you have APIs for your main application like creating tenants and so on then your solution is better so you can separate the apis meant for your main application and tenant.php is for you tenant APIs
but if all your APIs are for tenant then you can use api.php while I would still prefer using tenant.php so it can easily adapt if you need app APIs later

and while adding your tenant.php to RouteServiceProvider you can add it either as web or api based on your preference and needs

Comment: In my case, I have a central app, and tenants app. So each user has his own management profile (tenant) and I have a central app that manages all tenants and other things like this. Maybe later I will also want to create a mobile app. This was one of the reasons I asked this question. Do you think I can use tenan.php as api for each tenant? Is this also the best choice for the react js component to communicate with the laravel controller? Isn't there any way for me to use api.php for the central domain and for tenants?